# I cant find a difinitive way to save the state of a spinner in onSaveInstanceState, and recall it . . . please help

Tags: android, save, spinner, savestate

I cant find a difinitive way to save the state of a spinner in onSaveInstanceState, and recall it . . . please help.

I have spent hours looking and I cannot find anything about this. . . . I only want it temporarily. i do not want to use SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**for spinner i think you use arrayList so you have to save arrayList**

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        outState.putStringArrayList("arrUserIds", arrUserIds);


        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

**and you can restore arrayList onRestoreInstanceState method**

```
@Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        arrUserIds = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("arrUserIds");

        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
```